# Disgraceful shutdown of Camel Route

Tags: java, apache, jms, apache-camel, activemq-classic

How can I shutdown a Camel route context disgracefully?

As soon as I click the button, the Camel route should stop immediately. I don't want any delay.

Each time I do a `camelroute.context.stop()`, it takes some time to stop, and in that time since the route was active earlier queues and dequeues the messages are sent to the target queue.

I want to stop the route mid-way when I click the desired button.

Is there a way to handle it?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [`timeout` property](https://camel.apache.org/maven/camel-2.15.0/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/impl/DefaultShutdownStrategy.html#setTimeout(long)) of the `DefaultShutdownStrategy`.

Try setting it to zero in your Camel Context:

```
<bean id="shutdownStrategy" class="org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy"> 
    <property name="timeout" value="0"/>
</bean>
```

The value is in seconds by default.

Also, have a look at [Graceful Shutdown](https://camel.apache.org/graceful-shutdown.html) in the Camel docs, if you haven't yet.

---

**EDIT 1:** The `DefaultShutdownStrategy` [does not allow 0 timeouts](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/camel-core/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/impl/DefaultShutdownStrategy.java#L170). You could try setting it to **1 NANOSECOND** which might help:

```
<bean id="shutdownStrategy" class="org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy"> 
    <property name="timeout" value="1"/>
    <property name="timeUnit" value="NANOSECONDS" /
</bean>
```

Alternatively, you can implement your own `ShutdownStrategy` if it's really important for you to guarantee absolute immediate shutdown.